# connect power bi browser to azure blob storage

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, powerbi-desktop

I wanted to ask if it is possible to connect an azure blob storage to power bi service (or power bi browser). I only have the online version of power bi and not the desktop version.

I've seen that you can easily connect it in the desktop version with the "get data" button. However, I've not found a similar button in the online version, only that you can connect to excel or csv or manually. (see picture attached) Does anyone know how to connect it with the online version? Or is this not possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!![!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to connect Azure Blob Storage to Power BI Service directly like we do in Power BI desktop. You need to use Power BI Desktop to create a report and then publish it to Power BI Service.

Below are the steps to do this.

- Open Power BI Desktop and select *Get Data*.
- In the Get Data window, select Azure -> Azure Blob Storage.
- Enter the storage account name and account key, and then click *Connect*.
- Select the blob that contains the data and then select Edit to open the Power Query Editor.
- In the Power Query Editor, Transform and shape the data as required.
- Once the data is in the format that you want, select *Close & Apply* to load the data into Power BI Desktop.
- Create your report in Power BI Desktop, and then publish it to any of the required workspace in Power BI Service.
- Once your report is published to Power BI Service, you can refresh the data as needed and share the report with others.

-By this, you can access the data from Azure blob storage in power bi service

**Reference:**
[Data sources for the Power BI service - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-get-data#other-data-sources)

> This article covers the data source types you can connect to from the Power BI service. There are many other types of data sources. To use these other data sources in the Power BI service, you might need to use Power BI Desktop or Excel's advanced data query and modeling features first.

Comment: I am using power bi desktop now. I would like to connect all files from a specific folder within a container of a blob storage. When I select the container, it automatically connects to the first folder present in the container. Do you know how can I access/select one of the other folders? Thanks a lot in advance!! @Aswin

Comment: Are you using blob storage? or Datalake storage?

Comment: blob storage @Aswin